# error can not resolve symbol TabLayout and 'design

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-tablayout, android-design-library

Please help: I got error when import `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`
It say `"can not resolve symbol 'design'`

My build.gradle:

```
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

     dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
         {
             exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
         })
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26'
         compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26'
         testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You forgot to add design support library. Just add this dependencies in your `gradle app` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'
```

[**Design Support Library**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design)

> The Design package provides APIs to support adding material design components and patterns to your apps.
>
> The Design Support library adds support for various material design components and patterns for app developers to build upon, such as `navigation drawers`, `floating action buttons (FAB)`, `snackbars`, and `TabLayout`.

Or AndroidX dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

Comment: It's OK for importing the TabLayout but java still can not resolve letter "R", I synced project with Gradle but it not work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It show Error:(46) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_' in package 'android'

Comment: I have found the error, I just made a typo in the layout file so it generate error

Comment: @NadeemBhat happy to help you

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when migrating to androidx. You have to add this to your gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Also, the location of the TabLayout has changed. From

```
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

to

```
com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```

Here are the [class mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) for androidx.
Here is the new [documentation for the TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

With **Androidx** and the [**Material Components library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md) use:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

**OLD (Support Libraries):**

As you can check in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design) if you want to use the [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) you have to add this dependency:

```
com.android.support:design:26.0.2
```

Add in your `build.gradle` in the `dependencies` block:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Replaced this:

```
android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

With this:

```
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
```

and worked for me! ;-)

---

You need to add to build_gradle (APP):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```