# Cannot resolve symbol shows in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-styles

I am running android studio 3.1.2. In Miwok project's `styles.xml` it shows some red mark and cannot resolve symbol `"Theme";` `"Widget.AppCompat.Light";` `"Widget.Design"; "TextAppearance.Design"`. I also Sync project with gradle file and it shows some error.

I attached a screenshot of the sync result.

[image]

This is the miwok `styles.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_color</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MiwokAppBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <!-- App bar style -->
    <style name="MiwokAppBarStyle" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <!-- Remove the shadow below the app bar -->
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for a tab that displays a category name -->
    <style name="CategoryTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CategoryTabTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Text appearance style for a category tab -->
    <style name="CategoryTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textColor">#A8A19E</item>
    </style>
```

This is build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this article: [import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout; error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194684/import-android-support-design-widget-tablayout-error)

It worked for me.

My working gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.holtnet.arlingtontourguide"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```